# Update XML file in j2me

Tags: xml, java-me

I have one one `books.xml` file with some data like this

```
<BookDetails>
<Book>
<name>J2ME</name>
<author>abc</author>
<price>123</price>
</Book>
<Book>
<name>java</name>
<author>xyz</author>
<price>1234</price>
</Book>
</BookDetails>
```

I need to update the price of book which name is java. I need to update this xml file with new content.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JSoup a java library that you'll probably could use for your java-me environment. Once you have the library in your classpath you can convert your xml into a Dom tree with the following code where you import:

```
import org.jsoup.*
import org.jsoup.nodes.*
```

To then use the JSoup and Document classes to parse the xml:

```
String xml = "<BookDetails><Book><name>J2ME</name><author>abc</author><price>123</price</Book>" +
"<Book><name>java</name><author>xyz</author><price>1234</price></Book></BookDetails>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
```

And then use the following method to update the price of your xml book in memory:

```
public void updatePrice(Document doc, String bookName, String newPrice){
    for(Element name : doc.select("book name")){
        if(name.ownText() == bookName){
          name.parent().getElementsByTag("price")[0].text(newPrice);
     }
    }

}
```

A method that you could call easily:

```
updatePrice(doc, "java", "234");
```

As I said before that would update the xml in memory, then you would need to save the modified xml represented by the variable doc in your file.